# Why this function doesn't exceed Python recursion limit?

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort, cpython

I'm writing a quick sort function, here is the code :

```
def quick_sort(list_demo = [x for x in range(1100000)]):
    if not list_demo:
        return []
    else:
        # pivot = list_demo[0]
        lst = [list_demo[0], list_demo[-1], list_demo[len(list_demo) // 2]]
        pivot = sorted(lst)[1]
        smaller = quick_sort([n for n in list_demo[1:] if n <= pivot])
        bigger = quick_sort([n for n in list_demo[1:] if n > pivot])
        global times
        times += 1
        print("now is ", times)
        return smaller + [pivot] + bigger
```

And as I know, Python has a default recursion limit = 1000, but my code successful runs

After searching Stack Overflow, I didn't find any connected information about what recursion depth is, so I want to know, in Python, what recursion depth limit is ? **function calling times** or **father tree depth** ?

Captures :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l56D7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3BdI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, it is not clear what you question is. Are you asking why your function does not exceed the recursion limit? If so, have you tried adding an extra "depth" parameter to your function to see how "deep" the recursion actually gets? At a glance, it looks like your example will never get more than ~20 calls deep.

Comment: @Brian thanks for your replying bro, and yes I will update my question to be clear. actually I want to ask what the Recursion Depth is ? the called times of itself, or the father tree depth ? If it is called times, I have a global variable, and it is increased from 1 to 1 million... apologise for this question as I really cannot find any references on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brian, hi bro, finally I get it ! anyway, thanks for your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, finally I figured it out.

I forgot how the program runs :

1. bigger line won't run until smaller line finished
2. smaller line will continue call quick_sort() again
3. and again, the second smaller will call the 3rd quick_sort.
4. about log2(1000000) times, the smaller lines all finish
5. so the most calling times is just 20 times, far less than recursion limit.